# Will I automagically leave my campaign when it is over?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

When this one hit level 10 he excitedly went to do some PVP. This one didn't know anything about the system and foolishly set his home to a veteran campaign because all the other ones were "full" for the Dominion. At first it didn't click that it mean veteran level and this one got a message to the tune of "It will cost Alliance points to switch your home campaign, but the first one is free."

This one is now in a Cyrodiil focused guild and wants to join their army to protect the Dominion. When this one tried to switch campaigns to join his guild, he was told it would cost 15,000 AP! This one chose to leave later(in a week or so) which didn't have a price tag attached to it. Imagine this one's surpise when he finds out that they took almost half of his AP, he had 12k and now has only 6k! This one is now a very angry Kajiit!

Will this one's home campaign be reset after the timer runs out? What will his new home be, if it is set to one at all? Thank you, and warm sands my friends!

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a legitimate and answerable question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't do anything, you'll simply stay in your campaign for the next duration (and so on).

However, you can just open the campaign window and pick a new **Home Campaign**. (as you did). Once doing so, you'll be asked, whether you want to switch immediately or after the end of the current campaign duration (the later is cheaper).

You can just tell the game to switch once the campaign is over (pick the non-veteran campaign). Once your current campaign is over, you'll switch **Home Campaigns** as selected.

Till then, just assign your **Guest Campaign** to the non-veteran campaign. This way you're able to join that one as well (but you can't become emperor there and won't profit off its bonuses while outside Cyrodiil).